# Withdrawal in Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting an error "UserRoom object has no attribute 'images'".

[image]

models.py

```
class UserRoom(models.Model):
    objects = None
    categoty = [
        ('President Lux', 'President Lux'),
        ('Lux', 'Lux'),
        ('Double', 'Double'),
        ('Standard', 'Standard'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=categoty, verbose_name='Категория')
    room_num = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Доступные номера для категории')
    about = models.TextField(verbose_name='Подробности')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена')
    img360 = models.FileField(verbose_name='Фотография в 360')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номер (About)'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Номера (About)'


class UserImg(models.Model):
    objects = None
    name = models.ForeignKey(UserRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='img2')
    img = models.FileField(upload_to='User img', verbose_name='Фотография')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фотографию'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фотографии'
```

views.py

```
class UserRoomViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = UserRoom.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserRoomSer
```

serializers.py

```
class UserImgSer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserImg
        fields = '__all__'


class UserRoomSer(ModelSerializer):
    images = RelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=UserImg.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = UserRoom
        fields = [
            'name', 'room_num', 'about', 'price',
            'img360', 'images',
        ]
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'room', UserRoomViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Please help me with this problem I can't get json.

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "img": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "img": ""
        }
    ],
    "name": "",
    "room_num": "",
    "about": "",
    "price": "",
    "img360": ""
}
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just set the `related_name` field to get the reference from `UserRoom` model.

```
class UserImg(models.Model):
    objects = None
    # here I set the related_name attribute in the `name` field
    name = models.ForeignKey(UserRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='img2', related_name = 'images') 
    img = models.FileField(upload_to='User img', verbose_name='Фотография')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фотографию'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фотографии'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фотографию'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фотографии'
```

Comment: now throw an error : NotImplementedError at /room/3/
RelatedField.to_representation() must be implemented for field .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
class Meta:
    model = UserRoom
    fields = [
        'name', 'room_num', 'about', 'price',
        'img360', 'images',
    ]
```

You are trying to refer to `'images'` as it was field. But it's not in your model.
You can delete it.

Alternatively, you can add them to you model as `ManyToManyField`:

```
class UserRoom(models.Model):
    ...
    images = models.ManyToManyField('UserRoomSer', ...)
```